# How to ensure that an object does not outlive its factory

Tags: rust, lifetime

Lets say I have a factory of objects:

```rust
struct Object;
struct Factory;

impl Object {
    pub fn new() -> Object { Object{} }
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn new() -> Factory { Factory{} }
    pub fn create() -> Object { Object::new() }
}
```

How can you ensure that objects created by the factory do no outlive the factory? In other words, how to make code like this not compile:

```rust
let factory = Factory::new();
let object = factory.create();
drop(factory); // Some kind of lifetime compile error
```

Feel free to use any wrappers/containers to keep track of everything, as long as the compiler knows that something's up. I have tried returning a lot of different things myself, including `&RefCell<Object>`, but I always run into a wall and end up starting over.

Answer (score 4):

Rust has a lifetime/borrow-checking mechanism to ensure references do not outlive the referenced object. You can use the same principles to guarantee that `Object`s do not outlive their `Factory`. All you need is for `Object` to have a lifetime annotation that is bound to the `Factory` like so ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e5894494a7af0d878f1f2ed96c21e6a)):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Factory;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Object<'a> {
    // You can keep a reference to the factory if that's useful
    factory: &'a Factory,
    
    // Or you can save the bytes by using PhantomData instead
    // dummy: PhantomData<&'a Factory>,
}

impl Object<'_> {
    pub fn new(factory: &Factory) -> Object<'_> { Object { factory } }
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn new() -> Factory { Factory {} }
    pub fn create(&self) -> Object<'_> { Object::new(self) }
}

fn main() {
    let factory = Factory::new();
    let object = factory.create();
    drop(factory);

    // Just dropping the factory wouldn't cause an error unless the Object had
    // a Drop implementation or was used after the factory was dropped, so
    // trying to "use" the object by printing it after the factory was dropped
    // won't be allowed
    println!("{:?}", object);
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `factory` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:25:10
   |
24 |     let object = factory.create();
   |                  ---------------- borrow of `factory` occurs here
25 |     drop(factory);
   |          ^^^^^^^ move out of `factory` occurs here
26 | 
27 |     println!("{:?}", object);
   |                      ------ borrow later used here
```

Comment: This works, but still has one issue: the factory becomes immutable. Is there a nice way to still be able to call mutable functions on the factory?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not using this mechanism. And without it you'd have to resort to runtime checks instead of compile-time errors.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference to the factory in the object. This will make it impossible to drop (or mutate) `factory` before its outstanding objects are dropped.

The code below fails with a lifetime error because it tries to make `object` outlive `factory`:

```rust
struct Object<'a> {
    factory: &'a Factory
}
struct Factory;

impl<'a> Object<'a> {
    pub fn new(factory: &Factory) -> Object { Object{factory} }
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn new() -> Factory { Factory{} }
    pub fn create(&self) -> Object { Object::new(self) }
}

fn main() {
    let _object = {
        let factory = Factory::new();
        let object = factory.create();
        object
    };
}
```